# Reading and writing in .NET from and to Wordpress: XML-RPC or AtomPub?

Tags: .net, wordpress, xml-rpc, atompub

I need to read out posts and maybe write back comments to a WordPress blog.

I found some documentation on their API's XML-RPC and AtomPub.

But what would be the recommended way to go. XML-RPC seems more documented, as far as I can see.

Any experiences/recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say [XML-RPC/MetaWeblog](http://www.xmlrpc.com/metaWeblogApi) because it seems to have better support for clients, and it is geared toward blogs. The only client I've seen for AtomPub is [Windows Live Writer](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-writer).

In AtomPub's defense, I found it fairly easy to implement given only the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023). I've posted the libraries I developed on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/atom-library/).